# Elixir Map - Group by and order fields

Tags: elixir

In Elixir i have this map

```
   my_map =  [%{ user_id: 1, user_name: "David", gamer_id: 100, gamer_name: "John"  },
    %{ user_id: 1, user_name: "David", gamer_id: 101, gamer_name: "Bil"  },
    %{ user_id: 1, user_name: "David", gamer_id: 103, gamer_name: "Ruk"  },
    %{ user_id: 2, user_name: "Ron", gamer_id: 104, gamer_name: "Sam"  },
    %{ user_id: 2, user_name: "Ron", gamer_id: 105, gamer_name: "Sean"  }]
```

I want to transform that to below output

Output :

```
[%{ user_id: 1, username: "David", 
    games: [
        %{
            gamer_id: 100,
            gamer_name: "John"
        },
        %{
            gamer_id: 101,
            gamer_name: "Bil"
        },
        %{
            gamer_id: 103,
            gamer_name: "Ruk"
        }
    ]
},
%{ user_id: 2, username: "Ron", 
    games: [
        %{
            gamer_id: 104,
            gamer_name: "Sam"
        },
        %{
            gamer_id: 105,
            gamer_name: "Sean"
        }
    ]
}]
```

I tried Enum.group_by and all but could not achieve it

my_map |> Enum.group_by(fn(x) -> x.user_id end)

Any insight on how to achieve this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `my_map` is invalid and looks more like a list, correct?

Comment: Corrected please check now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the third argument of `Enum.group_by` to extract the `gamer_id` and `gamer_name` and then do a little processing using `Enum.map`:

```
my_map =  [%{user_id: 1, user_name: "David", gamer_id: 100, gamer_name: "John"},
           %{user_id: 1, user_name: "David", gamer_id: 101, gamer_name: "Bil"},
           %{user_id: 1, user_name: "David", gamer_id: 103, gamer_name: "Ruk"},
           %{user_id: 2, user_name: "Ron", gamer_id: 104, gamer_name: "Sam"},
           %{user_id: 2, user_name: "Ron", gamer_id: 105, gamer_name: "Sean"}]

my_map
|> Enum.group_by(&Map.take(&1, [:user_id, :user_name]), &Map.take(&1, [:gamer_id, :gamer_name]))
|> Enum.map(fn {k, v} -> Map.put(k, :games, v) end)
|> IO.inspect
```

Output:

```
[
  %{
    games: [
      %{gamer_id: 100, gamer_name: "John"},
      %{gamer_id: 101, gamer_name: "Bil"},
      %{gamer_id: 103, gamer_name: "Ruk"}
    ],
    user_id: 1,
    user_name: "David"
  },
  %{
    games: [
      %{gamer_id: 104, gamer_name: "Sam"},
      %{gamer_id: 105, gamer_name: "Sean"}
    ],
    user_id: 2,
    user_name: "Ron"
  }
]
```

Comment: Is there a way to group_by without using user_name and to achieve the same result?

Comment: What do you want the code to do if there are two different names for a specific user id?

Comment: Actually i am dealing with a very big map.In that there are lot of user details attached like gender, age etc....I cannot put all those in group_by right...so only i asked.
From this Map.take(&1, [:user_id, :user_name])
to 
Map.take(&1, [:user_id])

any way....
Without using username there i want the above output is it possible?

Comment: No names are same only for user_id....For ex for user_id =1 the user_name is david only

Comment: Instead of `Map.take`, you can do `&Map.drop(&1, [:gamer_id, :gamer_name])`. Would that work for you? You could do the group by using just user id but then the solution would be more complicated than this.